# Gtk.jl getting started example button issue

Tags: macos, gtk, julia

I want to make a simple GUI application using Julia and Gtk, however when trying the Getting started example on Gtk.jl the button does not show up.

I am just getting started using both Julia and Gtk, and want to do a simple GUI application. However, following the very first Gtk.jl getting started example the window, but not the button, shows. I am on macOS Mojave.

At first I ran into a locale warning when importing the package:

```
"Gtk-WARNING **: 12:50:44.014: Locale not supported by C library. Using the fallback 'C' locale."
```

, however ignoring or fixing it using

```
export LC_ALL="en_US"
```

have made no difference. The example code (and installation) goes as follows (and I run it line-by-line in the REPL):

```
#One time installation
Pkg.add("Gtk")

#Getting started example
using Gtk

win = GtkWindow("My First Gtk.jl Program", 400, 200)

b = GtkButton("Click Me")
push!(win,b)

showall(win)
```

Which produce the expected window, but not the expected button.

Comment: That's a [reported issue](https://github.com/JuliaGraphics/Gtk.jl/issues/414) on MacOS.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks!

Comment: You might want to try the suggestion (i.e. downgrading `glib`) in [one of the comments](https://github.com/JuliaGraphics/Gtk.jl/issues/414#issuecomment-489621700).

Comment: Yeah, I saw that, but I'll just wait it out/try something else for now. Thanks for your help